# How to call POST and PUT API according to response of GET API in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

When my component is loaded i need to check my get api response. If I get `get API` `response == null` I need to post data using the same form. When my `get API` `response != null`, then I need to patch the values to the form and should able to update it using PUT API

I tried below way and got stuck as i'm trying to use reactive form. If i have two buttons with two click events, i can hide my post api button and show update api button for `get API` request, if it has value. Similar way I can show post request api button if `get API` req `response == null`

Html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onRegisterSubmit(form)" [formGroup] = "form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" >
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">
</form>
```

updated

```
    username;
    getResponse
    Constructor() {
      this.getVal()
    }

    getVal() {
      http.get<any>(API).subscribe(response => {
       this.getResponse= response;
       if (this.getResponse != null) {
          this.form.patchValue({.     //append the values to the form
            username: response.username,
          })

      })
    }

   onRegisterSubmit(form) {
   this.username = form.value
   console.log(form.value);
    if (this.getResponse != null) {
       //I want to enable update button and update api here
          return http.put<any>(api, this.username).subscribe(resposne => 
          console.log(response) )
        } if(response == null) {
          return http.post<any>(api, this.username).subscribe(resposne => 
          console.log(response) )
        //I want to send data using post method.
        }
 }
```

Comment: Not related to reactive forms, but please explain what is happening in your current code and how it's not working.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Like I'm not able to take it forward from here. Very new to angular. Like how can I handle submission?

Comment: @AluanHaddad But even If i check the data onSubmit(), if form is empty i want to call post API and if from has values then call put API. It will always call put API after filling the form, as form will be valid and non empty in both cases. That's where i'm getting confused.

Comment: I can't help you without more details sorry. Your approach seems reasonable, you just need a crash course in debugging.

Comment: The form has nothing to do with it. Once you realize that, you will be on your way to solving your problem.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Am i going in a right direction? I got an idea. Will update my question. Can you review it after  updating?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Can you review it now. I have updated my code

Comment: I can't say without knowing how your backend behaves when there is no existing resource at that URI and what it expects to receive. POSTING or PUTTING a username is probably incorrect.

Comment: I don't have any backend. Just getting ready to search a job after my graduation. Practicing real scenario. Assuming that i'm sending a JSON object to backend with the above case

Comment: Oh. In that case, I wouldn't do it that way. A well written, modern backend would return an HTTP 404 if there wasn't an existing object. Look into [`npm:json-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) which will give you a basic backend with standard behavior.

Comment: Also, proper factoring is important, logic like this shouldn't be so tightly interwoven with the form

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks :) . If you have time, can you put the same with good and standard coding method. I will be following same principles after checking it

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sorry to ask. I want to learn clean coding methods rather than writing a bad code which works tho

Comment: Sorry, I don't have more time. My advise would be to follow some tutorials like https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6 which has pretty solid advice (for the most part) and even provides a fake HTTP backend for you to work with. In terms of clean coding, think about the logical operations you want and define them as methods and then flesh them out. So `createOrUpdate(){}` needs to become `createOrUpate(data) {}` because it needs data to send to the server and do this iteratively, trying keeping methods to 10 lines preferably and no more than 20

Comment: @manojsai what issue you are facing with your current code?

Comment: @AakashGarg I don't have any backend provider. Don't know if this works or is this way good to do. I just want to check the response from get api after component loads and later wanna perform the operation as per response. If null fill the form and send using post API. If != null, patch the values to form and update the values using PUT API

Comment: It will work, but read about mergemap operator of rxjs, as nested subscriptions are not a suggested practice

Comment: @AakashGarg But how can it handle in my above solution? Actually constructor run when component loads. But at the same my click function will be triggered as it's in constructor too. If i add form.valid and check then it will only work for post api. For update api already form will be valid so click function will be fired immediately as it's in constructor. It shouldn't be triggered until I click update button

Comment: @AakashGarg Updated my code now, can you please review it

Comment: Its still nested subscription in a way, i am telling you to learn mergemap. Also google how to setup mockbackend and test your code.